# How can I import pandas correctly in python script via Rstudio

Tags: python, pandas, rstudio

I just failed to import pandas in python script via Rstudio and it also failed to install pandas by pip. I would appreciate it if you can tell the right way to import pandas. Thanks!

```py
import pandas as pd
> reticulate::repl_python()
Python 2.7.10 (/usr/bin/python)
Reticulate 1.12 REPL -- A Python interpreter in R.
>>> import pandas as pd
ImportError: No module named pandas
>>>
```

or install pandas in the terminal:

```sh
$ pip install pandas
```

it still showed the ImportError

Comment: Maybe you have more than 1 version of python... try $pip2.7 install pandas

Comment: you can always do `/usr/bin/python -m pip install pandas` to use the same Python which you run in Rstudio.

Comment: Thanks for answers! However, it still did not work and there are some errors.  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/73/fb/six-1.12.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
ERROR: matplotlib 1.3.1 requires nose, which is not installed.
ERROR: matplotlib 1.3.1 requires tornado, which is not installed.
Installing collected packages: six, python-dateutil, numpy, pandas
  Found existing installation: six 1.4.1
ERROR: Cannot uninstall 'six'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.